# SSMS 2008 is stuck because Connect to Server window is hiding

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Launching SQL Server Management Studio 2008 after rdp or similar display config funny business, the Connect to Server window is sometimes hiding in the corner of a monitor. The program seems stuck, although it's really just waiting for input in a window i can't see or easily drag into view. Clicking the mouse on the background window makes the 'ding' sound Windows makes when you click in a bad place. Answer retrieves the Connect to Server window.

Mildly more annoying workarounds include killing ssms in Task Manager and disabling monitors.

Might be nice if SSMS had a [/resetSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) switch like devenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alt+tab to Switch To ssms

[alt+space](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) for the window's System menu

down arrow to Move > enter key to select that menu item

left/right/up/down arrows to drag the window into view

ye olde windowse, FTW!